# Python Hash Tables

Tags: python, hashtable

I have those data I want to project. I need to create a hash table that when I enter a number it gives me a name.

Like this

```
  dd = {'Here Number' : [(Name Here)]}
    z='Here Number'
    dd[z]
    #It should give as result the Name
```

So when I try this I get error on the second part [(Name Here)]

What is the solution on this.

Any suggestions

Comment: Can we see *actual* code?

Comment: `'Here Number'` is not a number, and `(Name Here)` is not a string. If this is your actual code, it is very wrong somehow.

Comment: I suggest you read a basic introduction to Python dicts such as this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: -1 this question should go away, unless it is improved. Is this the actual code you typed? At minimum, say what error message you got. I'm betting it was an error because "Name" and "Here" are not defined python variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat your number as numbers:

```
    dd= { 1 : 'MyName' , 2 : 'YourName' , 3 : 'OurName' , 4 : 'TheirName' }
    z= 3
    result= dd[z]
    print( result )
```

If you want to treat your number as strings:

```
    dd= { '1' : 'MyName' , '2' : 'YourName' , '3' : 'OurName' , '4' : 'TheirName' }
    z= '3'
    result= dd[z]
    print( result )
```

Comment: what if i want to do something more advanced but with the same logic

Comment: have a bunch of numbers and if i enter any on them project a name

Comment: @user2693902 "more advanced" in what way?

Comment: @user2693902  Do you mean that each name can have a bunch of different numbers?  In that case, we also need to know if two different names could share the same number (or a group of numbers).

Answer (score 0):

If the `Name Here` is a string, it should be represented as `'Name Here'`. So the code should be:

```
dd = {'Here Number' : [('Name Here')]}
z='Here Number'
dd[z]
#It should give as result the Name
```